# .htaccess redirect if folder accessed directly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

**Folder Structure:**

```
myproject/
 documents/
   1/
    sample.pdf
```

I am allowing user to view the `.pdf` file but do not allow to view it when access directly through url. If someone access it using directly using below url, it redirects to access denied page.

```
http://localhost/myproject/documents/1/sample.pdf
```

The code used to achieve this is

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost .*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ denied.php [L]
```

Upon further testing, I found that although direct file access is not allowed, but user can still get to know the file upload path and can navigate to docuemnt folder.

```
http://localhost/myproject/document/
```

which list down all the files uploaded.

How can I restrict user, if `document` folder OR sub-folders under `document` folder are accessed directly using URL.

The files inside the folder will be shown regardless of folder access as its happening now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert **just below `RewriteEngine` line** to deny direct entry to `/document` URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /document [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

Comment: And it blocks the files too.

Comment: Does not work with the code to hide direct file access as mentioned above.

Comment: Or it could be redirected to somewhere ?

Comment: I had a typo, it is fixed. Can you test again?