# Disable folder or subfolder with htaccess and use custom pages when redirect

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
project
  - lib
  - assets 
      * img
      * css
      * plugin
         * boostrap
  - function 
  - error_document
     * 403.php
  - index.php
```

Hello i want to redirect not show url when user/visitor access folder

example

when user acces folder or sub folder like lib,assets,img,css,plugin,boostrap,function,error_document

**localhost/project/lib**

**localhost/project/assets/css/**

then redirect to error_document/403.php  but not show url redirect

**localhost/project/error_document/403.php**

im already try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380705/htaccess-redirect-if-folder-accessed-directly) but i cannot set redirect to error_document/403.php then i must create file .htaccess in sub folder
 (lib,assets,function,error_document) i want to only .htaccess in folder project and redirect not show url redirect

this is my htaccess in folder lib

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /lib [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Help, me thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks for sub-directories under `project`. You need to add this in your root or `project` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /error_document/403.php [L]
```

Comment: when access folder  lib 
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404

Comment: Do you have `localhost/error_document/403.php` file located? @MuhamadRidwansyah

Comment: Please show me your .htaccess file contents after inserting these three lines. @MuhamadRidwansyah

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/framework/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . /error_document/403.php [L]

</IfModule>

Comment: And trying to access `localhost/framework/lib` produces that error in your first comment?

Comment: If `lib` exists and is a directory second condition should catch it but if it doesn't exist a `404` error will be thrown.

Comment: im still confused @revo